# About the English grammar for wishing

Tags: grammar

Consider:

> I would have played football tomorrow.

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Your question is unclear, please write it clearer. [The English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be a better place for you to look for help.

Comment: This is not the correct or at least not the ideal construction if you indicating that you desire or wish to play football tomorrow. Something like, 'I wish to play football tomorrow', would be better. This construction would only be used if there was a 'but' that prevents you playing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. But the statement calls for more explanation in it or following it. Your statement indicates that although you wish to play football tomorrow, for some reason you will not be able to. You need to complete the statement by specifying that reason. Either in the same sentence or another sentence following it or in the context of the paragraph your sentence is in.